# Return list of all values that match criteria to one or more cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i to pick all zip codes(A:A) by city(C) and county (D)

[image]

I need to look like

[image]

is that posible? i need to remove all duplicates and get all zip codes for every county

Comment: So what is the desired result for Cabo Rojo.

Comment: @JvdV for Cabo Rojo:
"Bouqueron" => "Cabo Rojo" = 622; 
"Cabo Rojo" => "Cabo Rojo" = 623;
where is singe use that one, where is multiple zip use that all.

Comment: @JvdV if is easier i can merge City and county so then in one criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTER()`, where the 2nd parameter of `FILTER()` holds a boolean structure:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FILTER(A$2:A$30,(C$2:C$30=B2)*(D$2:D$30=C2)))
```

Comment: Sir one other way, if space is not required as delimiter then . `ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(A$2:A$30,(C$2:C$30=B2)*(D$2:D$30=C2)))` . SIr true `BOOLEAN` always wins the race =)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thank you... i make little changes and all works :) https://prnt.sc/Cp-juQG0uUCT

Comment: @SandiBudic I have not given the solution, thank JvdV Sir. I have shown an alternative.